# How to create a double dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, double

I'd like to create a dictionary inside a dictionary in python using function `setdefault()`.
I'm trying to make a list of names and dates of birth using fallow dictionary.

```
names = {'Will': 'january', 'Mary': 'february', 'George': 'march', 'Steven': 'april', 'Peter': 'may'}
dates = {'Will': '7/01', 'George': '21/03', 'Steven': '14/03', 'Mary': '2/02'}
```

I was tring to use set to achieve this:

```
res_dict = dict()
for v, k in names.items():
    for v1, k1 in dates.items():
        res_dict.setdefault(v, {}).append(k)
        res_dict.setdefault(v1, {}).append(k1)
return res_dict
```

but it give me an error.

The result should be:

```
res_dict = {'Will': {'january': '7/01'}, 'Mary' : {'february': '2/02'} ,'George': {'march': '21/03'}, 'Steven': {'april': '14/03'}, 'Peter': {'may': ''}}
```

How can I get the desired result using `setdefault()`?

Comment: Well, for starters, `items()` returns `(key, value)` pairs, not `(value, key)`.

Comment: Try to avoid naming variables as built-in classes - change `dict` to `res_dict` or something. Plus, dict does not have `append()` method.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. Your inner dictionary doesn't need to be a dictionary at all and will work equally well as a tuple. So you'll have {'Will': ('january', '7/01'), 'Mary': ('february', '2/02')} and so on. In fact, I'd argue that a tuple is conceptually clearer as your inner dictionary doesn't have a clear key-value mapping.

Comment: i agree with u but if in near futhure i'd like edite dates or month or both of them i'd not be able to do it bcuz 'tuple' objects does not support item assignment or changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
In [17]: results = {}

In [18]: for k, v in names.iteritems():
    results[k] = {v: dates.setdefault(k, '')}
   ....:
   ....:

In [20]: results
Out[20]: 
{'George': {'march': '21/02'},
 'Mary': {'february': '2/02'},
 'Peter': {'may': ''},
 'Steven': {'april': '14/03'},
 'Will': {'january': '7/01'}}
```

And as to your comment regarding adding `month` and `day`, you can add them similarly:

```
In [28]: for k, v in names.iteritems():
    results[k] = {'month': v, 'day': dates.setdefault(k, '')}
   ....:
   ....:

In [30]: results
Out[30]:
{'George': {'day': '21/02', 'month': 'march'},
 'Mary': {'day': '2/02', 'month': 'february'},
 'Peter': {'day': '', 'month': 'may'},
 'Steven': {'day': '14/03', 'month': 'april'},
 'Will': {'day': '7/01', 'month': 'january'}}
```

And if you want to omit `day` completely in the case where a value doesn't exist:

```
In [8]: results = {}

In [9]: for k, v in names.iteritems():
   ...:     results[k] = {'month': v}
   ...:     if dates.has_key(k):
   ...:         results[k]['day'] = dates[k]
   ...:
   ...:

In [10]: results
Out[10]:
{'George': {'day': '21/03', 'month': 'march'},
 'Mary': {'day': '2/02', 'month': 'february'},
 'Peter': {'month': 'may'},
 'Steven': {'day': '14/03', 'month': 'april'},
 'Will': {'day': '7/01', 'month': 'january'}}
```

And in the odd case where you know the date but not the month, iterating through the set of the keys (as @KayZhu suggested) with a `defaultdict` may be the easiest solution:

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: names = {'Will': 'january', 'Mary': 'february', 'George': 'march', 'Steven': 'april', 'Peter': 'may'}

In [3]: dates = {'Will': '7/01', 'George': '21/03', 'Steven': '14/03', 'Mary': '2/02', 'Marat': '27/03'}

In [4]: results = defaultdict(dict)

In [5]: for name in set(names.keys() + dates.keys()):
   ...:     if name in names:
   ...:         results[name]['month'] = names[name]
   ...:     if name in dates:
   ...:         results[name]['day'] = dates[name]
   ...:
   ...:

In [6]: for k, v in results.iteritems():
   ...:     print k, v
   ...:
   ...:
George {'day': '21/03', 'month': 'march'}
Will {'day': '7/01', 'month': 'january'}
Marat {'day': '27/03'}
Steven {'day': '14/03', 'month': 'april'}
Peter {'month': 'may'}
Mary {'day': '2/02', 'month': 'february'}
```

Comment: nice one, what about when if i'd like add to it `month` and `days` to get such result:
    `{'George': {'month' :'march', 'day' : '21/02'}}`

Comment: @user1768615 You can actually add them into a similar structure (see the edit, and your objective now makes more sense :) ).

Comment: Wow, u make python look like easy piece cake! :) one more thing, to advoice writing empty `'day' : '' ` valutes what should i do

Comment: @user1768615 I'm the bottom of the barrel on this site - wait until you see the rest of them :) As for how to handle empty values, it is more or less up to you and what you want to do with your program. Having an empty string (or `None`) is handy because it lets you do more Pythonic 'checks' for its existence (`if results['Peter']['day']: do stuff`). But I would say keep it (meaning don't remove the `day` key just because it doesn't exist) since it will make for easier coding in the rest of your program.

Comment: @RocketDonkey this solution will miss some results if there are keys in  `dates` but not in `names`, you will need to get the superset of them first

Comment: @KayZhu I was thinking about that too, but then started thinking that in this case, if you have a `date`, chances are you will have the corresponding `month` (since `date` is a subset of `month`). That's probably a little localized to this problem though :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey ah, yes in this case that should be a safe assumption to make.. I didn't look at the semantics of the dicts :)

Comment: @KayZhu Ha, looking at semantics of dicts is how I spend my Friday nights, apparently!

Comment: @RocketDonkey , @KayZhu what do u think about adding `dates.has_key()` to make check and it it result true then write dates else not?

Comment: @user1768615 That will see if a particular key exists, but in your case, it sounds like you know the key will exist (`Peter`, for instance), so you could say `if dates['Peter']: ...`, which will return `False` with your data above.

Comment: @user1768615 it depends on whether you would want the type of dict like `{'april': ''}` or no dict for `april` at all. I would say depends on your usage, both cases might make sense.

Comment: I'd like get as result smth like uhm... if there is `day = number` then display it else if there is no number in `day` dont show it and same with `month`. example `'Peter': {'month': 'may'},` he has got no day.

Comment: @user1768615 then you'd better off using `has_key` for this particular situation.

Comment: @user1768615 I agree with Kay Zhu.

Comment: `results = {} for k, v in names.iteritems(): if k not in results and names.has_key(k): results[k] = {names.setdefault('month', v)} for k, v in names.iteritems(): if k not in results and date.has_key(k): diz[k] = {names.setdefault('day', v)} return results` it give me error

Comment: @user1768615 Amending the answer now - I think that will get what you want (and I'm heading to bed but can help tomorrow if you'd like).

Comment: Alright, i appologiace and thanks you two for help :)
I'll try to figure out by my self :P else i wont learn it heh... thanks RocketDonkey and kay Zhu

Comment: @user1768615 Learning is what makes this site fun! See if the modified answer helps, and try to think through what is happening on each step. Best of luck with everything!

Comment: @RocketDonkey that code will always display `month` and only if `day` is missing it wont but what happen when `month` is missing :)?

Comment: I note that we can also write in place of `results[k] = {'month': v}` simply `result[k].setdefault('month', v)`

Comment: @user1768615 Gotcha - making what I think will be the final edit now (note that this borrows from KayZhu's technique of iterating through the set of the keys, since it is possible that one key will not necessarily be in the other).

Answer (score 1):

A simple one-liner:

```
In [38]: names = {'Will': 'january', 'Mary': 'february', 'George': 'march', 'Steven': 'april', 'Peter': 'may'}

In [39]: dates = {'Will': '7/01', 'George': '21/03', 'Steven': '14/03', 'Mary': '2/02'}

In [40]: dict((name,{names[name]:dates.get(name,'')}) for name in names)

out[40]: 
    {'George': {'march': '21/03'},
     'Mary': {'february': '2/02'},
     'Peter': {'may': ''},
     'Steven': {'april': '14/03'},
     'Will': {'january': '7/01'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need get the superset keys from `names` and `dates` first:

```
>>> for k in set(names.keys() + dates.keys()):
...     res_dict[k] = {names.setdefault(k, ''): dates.setdefault(k, None)}
...     
... 
>>> res_dict
{'Will': {'january': '7/01'}, 'Steven': {'april': '14/03'}, 'Peter': {'may': None},
 'Mary': {'february': '2/02'}, 'George': {'march': '21/03'}}
```

Otherwise, you will miss out results whose keys are in `dates` but not in `names`.